# Why does index only scan for the full table ends up in the same cost as just an Index Scan

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, indexing

PostgreSQL 9.4

The difference between `Index Only Scan` and `Index Scan` is that in the first case we don't have to read the actual page containing a row the `indexNode` points to to fetch result. We fetching it right from the index node therefore avoid wasting time and resources to perform additional random access (to the actual page) and check the row's visibility .

Now, I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE bar ( c1 integer, c2 text )
CREATE TABLE foo ( c1 integer, c2 text )
```

that are filled similarly as

```
INSERT INTO foo
  SELECT i, md5(random()::text)
  FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS i;
```

Now, before working with the tables I ran `ANALYZE foo` and `ANALYZE bar` and then tried to execute

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT foo.c1
FROM foo foo
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar bar
ON foo.c1 = bar.c1
```

which the planner gave me the following result

```
Merge Left Join  (cost=0.63..83633.47 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.018..731.525 rows=1000000 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (foo.c1 = bar.c1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using foo_c1_idx on foo  (cost=0.00..34317.36 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.009..216.308 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 1000000
  ->  Index Only Scan using bar_c1_idx on bar  (cost=0.00..34317.36 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.006..233.899 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 1000000
```

Note, that the node is `Index Only Scan`. But if I try this:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT *
FROM foo foo
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar bar
ON foo.c1 = bar.c1
```

the plan will be

```
Merge Left Join  (cost=0.63..83633.47 rows=1000000 width=74) (actual time=0.014..738.559 rows=1000000 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (foo.c1 = bar.c1)
  ->  Index Scan using foo_c1_idx on foo  (cost=0.00..34317.36 rows=1000000 width=37) (actual time=0.007..194.479 rows=1000000 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using bar_c1_idx on bar  (cost=0.00..34317.36 rows=1000000 width=37) (actual time=0.004..210.758 rows=1000000 loops=1)
Total runtime: 758.261 ms
```

And the cost with `Index Scan` and `Index Only Scan` are the same, but in my case the query performed with `Index Only Scan` is 6 times faster that the last one.

***QUESTION:*** Why is the planner produce such strange cost? I ran ANALYZE to make sure I have the latest statistic about the tables.

Comment: The second query _has_ to read the whole table because you are using `select *` (thus requesting the second columns as well). And querying a two-column table isn't really that much more expensive than a single column index (and the runtimes of both queries do prove that)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, but shouldn't have been that reflected in total cost? The costs are the same, that's what confused me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "the costs are the same", because the *are* different (731 vs. 738).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, I talked about the relative cost of the `Merge Left Join` node` which is `83633.47`.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think because your supposed index only scan cannot really make use of indexes. It's a left outer join without any conditions at all, so indexes are useless on it.